# xcodebuild "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}

Tags: xcode, travis-ci

Getting this error when running unit tests on Xcode 10 / Swift 4.2 on Travis CI with xcode10 image. Tests running properly from command line on local.

> xcodebuild Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}
>
> xcodebuild Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=4 "Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...}
>
> Testing failed:
>       xctest encountered an error (Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted)
>
> ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED **

Don't recall having seen this "connection interrupted" error before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trying different things, including turning off tests parallelization, as Brian suggested before, we figured out this seems to be related to having both *multiple destinations* and *parallelization*.

There is a new `-disable-concurrent-destination-testing` flag that can be passed to `xcodebuild`, to force multiple destinations to be run sequentially.

By using this flag, we can enable both test parallelization and randomization while testing multiple destinations, all in a single command.

```
xcodebuild -scheme <YourScheme> -destination <DestinationA> -destination <DestinationB> -quiet -disable-concurrent-destination-testing test-without-building
```

This seems to be working well both locally and on CI servers.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this as well on some Xcode 10 and 10.1 Beta agents as well.  After our team turned off parallel testing it seemed to work correctly again.

I'm not sure if turning off parallel testing is a good solution for you, but it worked for us.  I can't find any documented bugs yet that say this is an issue.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. After much testing, I found the same, turning off parallelization solved the issue in one way. I'd elaborate this in a separate answer.